# URL query params or media type params (in Accept header) to configure the response to an HTTP request?

Tags: api, http, rest, mime-types, mime

I'm working on designing a REST API that can respond with a variety of formats, one of which is a plain text format which can be configured to show or hide certain aspects from the response (e.g. section headings or footnotes). The traditional way that this is done is via URL query parameters, both to indicate the desired response type and the configuration options, for example:

```
http://api.example.com/foo-book/ch1/?format=text&headings=false&footnotes=true
```

However, a more elegant RESTful way to indicate the desired response type (instead of the `format=text` URL query param) is to use the `Accept` header, for example:

```
Accept: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Now, in addition to URLs, media types can take parameters per [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) and as seen in the ubiquitous `text/html; charset=utf-8` and in `Accept` headers like `audio/*; q=0.2`. It's also [shown](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1566460) that vendor-crafted MIME types can define their own parameters like:

```
application/vnd.example-com.foo+json; version=1.0
application/vnd.example-info.bar+xml; version=2.0
```

So for previously-registered MIME types like `text/html` or `application/json`, is it acceptable to include custom parameters for an application's needs? For example:

```
Accept: text/plain; charset=utf-8; headings=false; footnotes=true
```

This seems like an elegant RESTful solution, but it also seems like it would be violating something. [RFC 2046 §1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-1) says:

```
Parameters are modifiers of the media subtype, and as such do not
fundamentally affect the nature of the content.  The set of
meaningful parameters depends on the media type and subtype.  Most
parameters are associated with a single specific subtype.  However, a
given top-level media type may define parameters which are applicable
to any subtype of that type.  Parameters may be required by their
defining media type or subtype or they may be optional.  MIME
implementations must also ignore any parameters whose names they do
not recognize.
```

Note this last sentence:

```
MIME implementations must also ignore any parameters whose names they do not recognize.
```

Does this mean that a client would be non-conforming if they recognized a `footnotes=true` parameter of the `text/plain` media type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems to me that the distinction should run as follows:

**Accept header parameters** pertain to the packaging of the response.

- Media type (e.g. `application/json`)
- Character encoding (e.g. `charset=utf-8`)
- Structure (e.g. vendor extensions that specify the "doctype"; 
  `application/vnd.example-com.foo+json; version=1.0`)

**Query parameters** pertain to resource(s) as addressed.

- Components (e.g. headings and footnotes)
- Optional features (e.g. formatting)
- Constraints (especially when addressing a range of like resources)

Comment: What if a query parameter is specific to a particular response type? For example a `line-length` parameter for `text/plain`: if a URL exists such as `http://api.example.com/foo?line-length=74` and if I request it with `Accept: text/html`, should the query param simply be ignored? Or should the response contain a `Content-Location: http://api.example.com/foo` header along with the same URL in a `<link rel='canonical' href='http://api.example.com/foo'/>` (aka `<atom:link rel='self' href='http://api.example.com/foo'/>`) to indicate that the parameter wasn't considered when serving the response?

Comment: That probably belongs in the Accept header, with Vary: Accept being sent as well (thanks, @fumanchu).

Comment: One thing that makes me nervous about a heavy reliance on Accept parameters: a) the level of client support and b) the technical expertise of the people consuming the API. Sometimes RESTful design principles run the danger of committing architecture astronautry at the expense of user experience

Comment: Agreed. I think that both purer server-driven negotiation should be accompanied by agent-driven negotiation to make accomodations for client limitations, e.g. pulling in data via JSON-P or via PHP's `file_get_contents()` for which you can't suppled your own request headers.

Answer (score 2):

David Eyk is correct.

If you are changing the Entity returned, it should be in the URI. Anything else will break all sorts of things like caching etc.

The "format" inside the URI however is mostly wrong. If you can, use Accept. Response headers are already in place to provide a smooth ride.

However, if you are unable to use Accept (like in a standard webbrowser) I recommend using a DOS extension or similar to override the Accept.

```
e.g.
/image (is the resource)
/image.jpg
/image.gif
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Regarding the `format` parameter, I realized that this would be the only real option for linking to an alternate format of a resource, per HTML5 example: `<link rel=alternate href="/en/pdf" hreflang=en type=application/pdf title="English PDF">`. Though perhaps this is kind of format-explicit link is not praiseworthy.

Comment: In theory, you should just be able to add `Vary: Accept` to the response headers and then nothing would break. But in practice, HTTP implementations can be sketchy on such details.